# Angular, read attribute from directive tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that looks like this:

```
<div class="slidesShow" interval="5" ng-controller="slideshowController" ng-init="init()">
    <img ng-repeat='item in slides' src="{{item.src}}" alt="{{item.alt}}" />
</div>
```

Can I get the value of the interval attribute in my controller function?

I have tried this:

```
angular.module('awsApp').controller('slideshowController', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.init = function () {
        console.log('unterval:' + $scope.attr.interval);
    };

});
```

This gives ne the error:
Error: $scope.attr is undefined

Can I acces this attribute? And if so, How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject attrs into the controller like

```
angular.module('my-app').controller('slideshowController', function ($scope, $http, $attrs) {
    console.log($attrs)

    $scope.init = function () {
        console.log('unterval:' + $attrs.interval);
    };

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9J7g5/)

Comment: I had already tried $attr but it needs to be $attrs Thank you Arun!